# Mamp: import large database

Tags: macos, drupal, mamp

I'm importing a large drupal database to my mac using mamp and I keep finding errors, the phpmyadmin can't import the database. can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please improve your question by reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For example: we need to see the error.

Answer (score 1):

Importing a large database through phpmyadmin is not recommended (it will typically hangup forever). It's much more efficient to use the command line through the Terminal.

First, make sure you can connect to your database from the command line with one of the following commands:

1/ If your root password isn't set:

```
mysql -u root
```

2/ or if you have a root password:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

3/ or if you have a specific username and password:

```
mysql -u username -p
```

---

If one of those commands execute correctly, you're good to go to the next step.

Notice you can exit the mysql interactive session anytime with entering:

```
exit
```

---

List your databases:

```
SHOW databases;
```

If you don't have your database listed here, you will need to create it:

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Then select your database:

```
USE database_name;
```

Finally, import the data from your sql file:

```
SOURCE "path/to/your/file.sql"
```

---

**Second method** (it suppose your database is already created)

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < path/to/your/file.sql
```